# How can I able to move the content up and down in AIR-Android ?

Tags: android, flash, apache-flex, air, air-android

I'm using Flash CS 5 and Flex 4, both to build an AIR application for android. I would like to know how to allow the user to move content(image or text) up and down(like a map,in this case only vertically).

Comment: 1st, in Flex, I tried with TextArea component with the song lyrics in it. So the user can scroll up and down using the scrollbar. But I rather want to see the lyrics with the background picture of an artist(looks more attractive), so I used Flash CS 5 to do just that. But since I have to set the document properties in Flash, the lyrics in the Text control chopped off after I published. I don't want that text to be chopped of, I want to allow the user to press and scroll the screen up and down to see the full lyrics in android device. Thank you and that's what I tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no touch UI controls available yet, so you need to implement it yourself. Here's a little bit of code that might help get you started. I wrote it on the timeline so that I could test it quickly. You'll need to make a couple adjustments if you're using it in a class.

The variable `content` is a MovieClip that is on the stage. If it is larger than the height of the stage, you'll be able to scroll it by dragging it with the mouse (or with your finger on a touch screen). If it is smaller than the height of the stage, then it won't scroll at all because it doesn't need to.

```
var maxY:Number = 0;
var minY:Number = Math.min(0, stage.stageHeight - content.height);
var _startY:Number;
var _startMouseY:Number;
addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);

function mouseDownHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    _startY = content.y;
    _startMouseY = mouseY;
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, stage_mouseMoveHandler, false, 0, true);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stage_mouseUpHandler, false, 0, true);
}

function stage_mouseMoveHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var offsetY:Number = mouseY - _startMouseY;
    content.y = Math.max(Math.min(maxY, _startY + offsetY), minY);
}

function stage_mouseUpHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, stage_mouseMoveHandler);
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stage_mouseUpHandler);
}
```

Alternatively, you could use the `scrollRect` property. That one is pretty nice because it will mask the content to a rectangular region for you. If you just change `y` like in the code above, you can draw other display objects on top of the scrolling content to simulate masking. It's faster than `scrollRect` too.